# Erro ao adicionar COUNT no CONCAT

Tags: mysql

Quando tento adicionar o `COUNT` ele retorna erro, mas quando eu tiro, o `script` funciona normal. Segue o erro:

`Invalid use of group function`

**Script:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
        CONVERT(
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT CONCAT(
                    TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
                    "(", COUNT(TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO), ")"
                ) 
                SEPARATOR ', '
            ) 
            USING 'utf8'
        ) AS NOME_PRODUTO,      
        TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO,
        TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
    FROM TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO     
    INNER JOIN TB_PEDIDO ON TB_PEDIDO.ID_PEDIDO = TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO  
    INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
    WHERE TB_PEDIDO.ID_PESSOA = 1
    GROUP BY TB_PEDIDO.ID_PEDIDO
```

Quero que retorne esse resultado:

```
Produto
--------------------------------
produto(2), testando(1), teste(4)
```

Eu segui esse site:

> http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

## Banco de dados:

<sub>**TB_PEDIDO:**</sub>

[image: TB_PEDIDO]

<sub>**TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO:**</sub>

[image: TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO]

<sub>**TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO_INGREDIENTE:**</sub>

[image: TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO_INGREDIENTE]

<sub>**TB_PRODUTO:**</sub>

[image: TB_PRODUTO]

<sub>**TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES:**</sub>

[image: TB_PRODUTOS_INGREDIENTES]

<sub>**TB_INGREDIENTES:**</sub>

[image: TB_INGREDIENTES]

Comment: acho que faltou um order by GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT CONCAT(
                    TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
                    "(", COUNT(TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO), ")"
                ) ORDER BY TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO
                SEPARATOR ', '
            )

Comment: @PedroRangel, não é o `order by`:/

Comment: voce poderia me mostrar sua base de testes com as respectivas tabelas?

Comment: @PedroRangel, Atualizado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Melhor Solução é processar isso na Aplicação, mas caso exista uma razão para se resolver no SELECT, sugiro você utilizar um sub-select da quantidade de itens de cada ID_PRODUTO.

Veja se funciona com a solução abaixo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
    CONVERT(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            DISTINCT CONCAT(
                TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
                "(", 
                (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TB_PRODUTOS AS SUB_PRODUTOS WHERE SUB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO),
                ")"
            ) 
            SEPARATOR ', '
        ) 
        USING 'utf8'
    ) AS NOME_PRODUTO,      
    TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO,
    TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
FROM TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO     
INNER JOIN TB_PEDIDO ON TB_PEDIDO.ID_PEDIDO = TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO  
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
WHERE TB_PEDIDO.ID_PESSOA = 1
GROUP BY TB_PEDIDO.ID_PEDIDO
```

Comment: Seu query resultou o seguinte erro: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM SUB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO),
                ")"
    ' at line 8 `

Comment: dupliquei o from sem querer, 
já arrumei

Comment: Funcionou Agora? eu editei!

Answer (score 1):

Campos em funções agregadoras como `max`,`min`,`avg` ou `count` devem ficar de fora da cláusula `GROUP BY`.

Tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO,
        CONVERT(
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                DISTINCT CONCAT(
                    TB_PRODUTOS.NOME_PRODUTO,
                    "(", COUNT(TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO), ")"
                ) 
                SEPARATOR ', '
            ) 
            USING 'utf8'
        ) AS NOME_PRODUTO,      
        TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO,
        TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
    FROM TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO     
    INNER JOIN TB_PEDIDO ON TB_PEDIDO.ID_PEDIDO = TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PEDIDO  
    INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTOS ON TB_PRODUTOS.ID_PRODUTO = TB_ITEM_PEDIDO_PRODUTO.ID_PRODUTO
    WHERE TB_PEDIDO.ID_PESSOA = 1
```

Comment: Não deu certo, resultou no seguinte erro: `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: @Exception o problema é o GROUP_CONCAT - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463171/using-count-in-group-concat . Logo mais faço a adaptação